# Looking for a book with two races, one who can use magic, one who can use machines

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a blurb recently in a bookstore while on holiday, I decided not to buy it at the time and now I am regretting it. From what I remember there were two races living together in harmony. One race could use magic but not use mechanical devices (even have difficulty using latches on doors) and the other race cannot use magic but is gifted with mechanical skills.

Comment: The only one that comes to mind is Zelazny's *Jack of Shadows.*

Comment: @Mihai - Actually, it made me think of Zelazny's [Changeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeling_%28novel%29) / [Madwand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madwand) books.

Comment: There's actually a great series about this theme : [Shadows of the Apt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Apt#Shadows_of_the_Apt_series). (It has multiple races which split along mechanical/non-mechanical lines).

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheMagicVersusTechnologyWar), which has a list of literature that meets your criteria.

Answer (score 3):

May it be **Darksword** from Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman?

Is a similar history where humankind is split in two: Magic users and non-magic users...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksword

Comment: While only some people can use magic, they don't appear to be limited, technology wise, in any way.  Certainly doors don't present a problem.  However, in general, places with a high 'magic content' may end up with fewer machines given a ready alternative.

Comment: True. But in the rest it was "similar" :)